# "error: cannot communicate with server" when trying to install IntelliJ snap package

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, intellij

I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html#snap).

This happened:

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic 
[sudo] password for user-1099869:  
error: cannot communicate with server: 
Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/intellij-idea-community: 
dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I then tried:

```
(xenial)user-109986@localhost:~$ systemctl status snapd.service 
Failed: to get properties: 
Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall snapd. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
sudo apt install snapd
sudo systemctl enable snapd
sudo reboot
```

Then try to install intellij-idea-community again.

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
```

Comment: OK, I'll try that. Thank you.